# Multiple dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, selectedindexchanged

i have 4 dropdownlist. when i change the 1st dropdown, onselectindexchanged i need to change all the remaining dropdown values.
I am working on it but i could change only the corresponding or next dropdown value on onselectindexchanged. Please provide me any example or guide me to any good link.
Pls help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the remaining dropdown values need to change too?

Comment: Please show us your relevant code too. It would help in pointing out the issue.

Comment: it need to be changed to the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set AutoPostBack of all dropdowns to true and need to add SelectedIndexChanged event for first three drop downs. On SelectedIndexChanged of first dropdown you need to set selected value of second and it will fire SelectedIndexChanged of second and there you will have code to set selected index of third and similarly you will do on wards.

In Html

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownlist2_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownlist3_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

1 
    2

*In code behind*

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       dropdownlist2.SelectedIndex = someIndexValue;
}

protected void dropdownlist2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       dropdownlist3.SelectedIndex = someIndexValue;
}

protected void dropdownlist3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       dropdownlist4.SelectedIndex = someIndexValue;
}
```

Comment: Oh.. I am sorry... i forgot it since i was in joy.. :P